# Elements and Unions

Tags: problem-solving

[image: Need help solving this problem step by step!]
Need help solving this problem step by step!

Comment: Can you share your thoughts so far? Do you understand what $R - S$ means?

Comment: One of these represents $R$.  Do you know which one?

Comment: Just in case this was a source of possible confusion, the shading is where "stuff" is at. For example, if we shaded EVERYTHING (in R, in S, and in U) then this set of "stuff"/shaded area is all of U.  If we shaded nothing then this would be the empty set.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** $R \setminus S =$ everything that is in $R$, but not in $S$.

Comment: Good grief! I saw someone downvote this then a second later it went back up, I really hope the people that use this site regularly aren't that angry at people that ask these sorts of questions.... if you don't think people should ask these sorts of questions, just move on to another!

Comment: I agree. When I see questions with no effort shown, the most I'll do is give a hint, like this.

Comment: But I think it raises some questions.  I don't think its our place to pass any judgment, they will get judged by their professors, I asked a question on meta recently (and quickly deleted it after realizing it got downvoted so quickly), I asked "Why bother downvoting a question like this when the user already has one rep". The result?  they might get suspended.... and guess what?!  They don't care!  They will just create another user#### account and go on asking questions.  Its time we as a community get the metaphorical stick out of our #$@.

Comment: Good job math s.e. put it on hold, whatever makes you feel smarter about yourself

Answer (score 2):

$B$ is the right answer.

$$R \cap S \neq \varnothing $$

$$x \in R, \text{ BUT } x \notin S, \text{ and as the intersection of R and S is different from the empty set,} \\ \text{ we have to subtract from R all the elements of S }$$

[image]